# I have a syntax error in my code for creating a trigger using sql. I use mysql version 14.14

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hey Guys I have a syntax error in my trigger I dont know why! I have 3 tables in a database for a sales company, namely ORDERS,SALESREPS AND PRODUCTS. Whenever an order is placed, I have to add that order to ORDERS table. The cost of the order is added to the SALES column in SALESREPS table. Note that salesreps is a table of people who sell products and the column sales stores total amount of sales by respective salesperson. Also,  The table PRODUCTS( which is a table having a list of all products and their details) contains a column  'quantity in hand'. SO when an order is placed, I have to reduce the number of orders from the quantity available before order of that product was placed.

I get a syntax error as

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON ORDERS AFTER INSERT AS 
>           UPDATE SALESREPS
>               SET SALES=SALES+INSERTED.AMOUNT' at line 2

Here is my code for trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
ON ORDERS AFTER INSERT AS
    UPDATE SALESREPS
    SET SALES=SALES+INSERTED.AMOUNT
        FROM SALESREPS,INSERTED
    WHERE SALESREPS.EMPL_NUM=INSERTED.REP;
    UPDATE PRODUCTS
    SET QTY_ON_HAND=QTY_IN_HAND - INSERTED.QTY
        FROM PRODUCTS,INSERTED
        WHERE PRODUCTS.MFR_ID=INSERTED.MFR
            AND PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID=INSERTED.PRODUCT;
```

Also, since my am updatin tables based on a inserted tuple , how do I refer to the inserted tuple??

Comment: There is no MySQL version "14.14"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple `syntax` problem here, but I think this is what you need

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE SALESREPS
       SET SALES=SALES+NEW.AMOUNT
     WHERE SALESREPS.EMPL_NUM=NEW.REP;
    UPDATE PRODUCTS
       SET QTY_ON_HAND= (QTY_IN_HAND - NEW.QTY)
     WHERE PRODUCTS.MFR_ID=NEW.MFR_ID
       AND PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID=NEW.PRODUCT;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Your first problem was with this line :

```
ON ORDERS AFTER INSERT AS
```

Which is reverted, it need to be

```
AFTER INSERT ON ORDERS
```

Notice that I removed the `AS`.

You were also missing the `FOR EACH ROW BEGIN/END`

Notice that at the beginning I specify the delimiters to be `$$` so the compiler know when to stop.

Also, `update` statement must not have a `from` clause, as you already specify which `table` you are updating on the first statement.

```
UPDATE SALESREPS
```

Next problem is when you tried to refer to the new value, well the specified keyword to access is is as simple as `new`.

Your last error was your condition `where products.mfr_id = new.mfr` you probably just made a typo here, you want to use `where products.mfr_id = new.mfr_id`

Comment: I did try those corrections before posting the question. It had given me these errors:                                                                                                            ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'NEW.MFR' in 'where clause'
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: Yes I did! The errors that I posted in my comment where what I got from your query! Could it be something related to my DBMS? Maybe there is a separated syntax for my version of mysql??

Comment: @user2983071 Try the new edit, if it works then I'll explain why it did not works before with more details. Don't worry, even if your version is different we will get it to work :) This is not a really hard problem.

Comment: Wow!! It worked! AmazinG! What was incorrect with my code and your earlier code??

Comment: @user2983071 I edited the post to give more details, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :).

Comment: Hahaha!! Thanks a ton man! :D I was banging my head over this for a long time! :P