# Trigger has an error at first action

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have trigger for update insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgBooking_update_seat
ON dbo.booking
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) BEGIN
       -- Handle insert or update
       UPDATE Seats 
       SET status = Bookings.statusBooked
       FROM dbo.seat Seats
       INNER JOIN INSERTED Bookings ON Bookings.noSeat = Seats.noSeat
   END 
END
```

This is my table `seat`. This table is list of my seats, this table has a `status` column which I set to 0 by default.

[image]

And this is my table `booking`. Every insert action I set `statusBooked` to 1 by default. If `end` is equal to current time then `statusBooked` will automatically updated to 0.

[image: booking table]

I want to automatically update `status` on `dbo.seat` to the same value as `statusBooked` on `dbo.booking`.

- If `statusbooked` is 1, then `status` should be updated to 1
- If `statusBooked` updates to 0, then `status` must be updated to 0 also

So status is reference `statusBooked` by noSeat. I write the trigger and it works.

But at first time (when all `dbo.seat` status is 0.) it won't work.

Example :

(when `status` is all 0) I did insert to `booking`(noSeat : 1-5), `statusBooked` was 1 but `status`(noSeat:1-5) stay 0. then I did insert for second time, it just works. I insert to `booking` again (noSeat : 1-7)`statusBooked` is 1 and `status`(noSeat : 1-7) is also 1. but `status` for noSeat 1-5 is still 0.

I only have 1 trigger at all. so what's the problem ?

Comment: is statusBook is calculated column?

Comment: calculated ? what do you mean ?

Comment: how do you automatically update to 0 column statusBoook?.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM dbo.seat Seats
INNER JOIN INSERTED Bookings
ON Bookings.noSeat = Seats.noSeat
```

I dont think you need this block of code in your trigger because you already mentioned that you are updating your Seats table in the line:

```
UPDATE Seats SET
```

I would suggest you to rewrite it like this and try again:

```
 UPDATE Seats SET
 status = Bookings.statusBooked
 WHERE Bookings.noSeat = Seats.noSeat
```

Also I would suggest you to try and use the keyword 'new' instead if INSERTED as I had some problems with triggers myself and I got this suggestion. Hope it helps you!
This was my question on triggers...Someone answered it, You can refer to it as well, here is the link:

[I have a syntax error in my code for creating a trigger using sql. I use mysql version 14.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383218/i-have-a-syntax-error-in-my-code-for-creating-a-trigger-using-sql-i-use-mysql-v/28383314?noredirect=1#comment45108910_28383314)

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:sql-server]. So `inserted` is correct and `new` would be incorrect.